# Will Websql stop for already built Electronjs Application as the Websql will stop next year or it will keep working

Tags: electron, web-sql, electron-vue

Really appreciate your support
I Built a couple of ElectronJs Apps that use Websql (they already working), I recently learnt that Websql will stop completely next year, my question is
-will this Apps stop working due to the websql stopping ?
or
-as the Apps are already built it will be work as is but i wont be able to use this feature in the future updates?

Should I start building this apps again using indexeddb or it will keep working

Answer (score 0):

As WebSQL is embedded in [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-projects/), which in turn is embedded in [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), should you decide to update Electron to a version that contains Chromium version 119 or newer, then WebSQL functionality within your application will no longer work (noting that WebSQL depreciation began in Chromium version 97).

Like any technology that is being phased out, it would be in your applications best interest to find an alternative to WebSQL and implement that before updating Electron past a Chromium version where your use of WebSQL stops working.

Of course, you can continue to use WebSQL if you so wish by not upgrade Electron but if your application has a user base, they may think differently as halting all future updates to Electron (thus Chromium as well) may create security holes in the future.

In summary:

> WebSQL will continue to function indefinitely if you **do not** update your version of Electron.

References:

- [Developer Chrome Blog - Web SQL deprecation timeline updated](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/web-sql-deprecation-timeline-updated/#:%7E:text=Web%20SQL%20was%20deprecated%20and,the%20Chrome%20DevTools%20Issue%20panel)
- [W3C - WebSQL Database](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)